# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Any'

Tags: swift, swift3

У меня есть массив в котором я храню имена юзеров. При попытке вывести имена в tableViewCell возникает ошибка

> **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Any'**

Вот мой код

```
var usersIn = [] as NSMutableArray
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let userList = usersIn[indexPath.row]

    if let username = userList {
        cell.textLabel?.text! = username as! String
    }

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return usersIn.count
}
```

Мне кажется при запуске этой строки `if let username = userList {
        cell.textLabel?.text! = username as! String
    }`  возникает ошибка

Чтобы заполнить массив я использую метод импорта даты с VC A к VC B.
Вот код с VC A

```
var usersInGame = [] as NSMutableArray
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any?) {
    print("start")
    print("OutputID: \(usersInGame)")

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "transData", sender: nil)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "transData" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! AlreadyStartViewController
        destination.usersIn = usersInGame as! [String] 
    }
}
```

Вот мой код с VC B

```
var usersIn:[String] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->          UITableViewCell {
     let cell = UITableViewCell()
     if usersIn[indexPath.row] != nil {
         cell.textLabel?.text! = usersIn[indexPath.row]
     }
     return cell
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int  {
     return usersIn.count
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы правильно подумали у вас проблема в проверке, поменяйте код на

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let username = usersIn[indexPath.row] as? String //Приводим к Optional строке и теперь там будет или строка или nil 

    // проверяем на nil
    if username != nil {
        cell.textLabel?.text? = username!
    }

    return cell
}
```

---

Вариант №2

```
var usersIn:[String] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text? = usersIn[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

или

```
var usersIn:[String?] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if usersIn[indexPath.row] != nil {
        cell.textLabel?.text? = usersIn[indexPath.row]!
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Вот такой вопрос, а почему нужно переменную сохранять как Optional и потом проверять не ровно ли nil ?

Comment: потому что по вашей ваш массив в том виде который вы записали тип [Any] а значит если там будет например число то  в строке `cell.textLabel?.text! = username as! String` будет ошибка . А привидением типа переменной к Optional String переводит все значения которые не строки в nil

Comment: Результат ошибка <<fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value>> и показывает что ошибка в этой функции

Comment: Но в массиве все ок, я проверял, при запуске выводит весь массив, а тут - нет

Comment: Андрей, помогите, пожалуйста, я уже долго думаю над этими ошибками и не понимаю что не так в коде

Comment: попробуйте код из примеров, и насколько обосновано использование NSMutableArray ?

Comment: Все методы не работают, ошибка такая же

Comment: покажите как вы заполняете массив, просто судя по тому что остальные варианты у вас выдают ошибку то проблема может быть только в том что на момент вызова метода ваш массив еще не заполнен

Comment: Посмотрите в мой вопрос, я там написал

Comment: и у вас еще ошибка, замените  ` cell.textLabel?.text! = ` на  ` cell.textLabel?.text? =

Comment: когда я изменил это - ошибка не выводится, но в клетки не выводит

Comment: или  `cell.textLabel?.text =`

Comment: ну а теперь проблема уже в создании cell вот дока
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623210-textlabel